# How table-layout: auto works with th/td width style

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I have tables with table-layout set to auto. And on my table cells I have width property set. However when I inspected actuall width of cells, whey were smaller then the ones I specified. Eg:

- width: 70px and actual width was <70px

What I did, I changed width to min-width, and now it seems to work. Cell width is never smaller than 70px

However I'm interested what is the implementation of table-layout: auto. For instance, do I have to specify my width properties on all cells, or only on thead>tr>th? Should I use width/min-width? I could not find detailed resource that explains how this algorithm works nor how it works in practise

Comment: I misread the question.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Table_Layout_Strategy

Comment: The automatic table layout algorithm is largely implementation-dependent. You won't find more than an informative summary in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#auto-table-layout).